# SQL GROUP BY Column Value

Tags: sql, group-by, ssms

When selecting the below data I want to make it so that I can group by the columns so that there should be all "Y". The below image shows how this currently looks;

[image]

[image]

The second image shows how the end result should look.

```
SELECT p.FirstName
    ,p.Surname
    ,CASE
        WHEN a.ActivityName = 'Jumping' THEN 'Y'
        ELSE 'N'
    END AS 'Jumping'
    ,CASE
        WHEN a.ActivityName = 'Dancing' THEN 'Y'
        ELSE 'N'
    END AS 'Dancing'
    ,CASE
        WHEN a.ActivityName = 'Walking' THEN 'Y'
        ELSE 'N'
    END AS 'Walking'
FROM #TempActivity a 
    INNER JOIN #TempPerson p ON a.AID = p.ActivityID
WHERE FirstName = 'John'
    AND Surname = 'Smith'
```

Below I have copied the entire table creation process so that you can see all the data and table structure. I release there is a betther way to design the tables in this instance but this is just acting an as an example so that i know the method to apply elsewhere;

```
CREATE TABLE #TempActivity(
AID INT
,ActivityName VARCHAR(100)
)

CREATE TABLE #TempPerson(
PID INT
,FirstName VARCHAR(100)
,Surname VARCHAR(100)
,ActivityID INT
)

INSERT INTO #TempActivity
VALUES (1,'Jumping')
    ,(2,'Dancing')
    ,(3,'Walking')

INSERT INTO #TempPerson
VALUES (1,'John', 'Smith', 1)
    ,(2,'John', 'Smith', 2)
    ,(3,'John', 'Smith', 3)
    ,(4,'Jane','Smith', 1)
    ,(5,'Jane','Smith', 2)

SELECT * FROM #TempActivity
SELECT * FROM #TempPerson

SELECT p.FirstName
    ,p.Surname
    ,a.ActivityName
  FROM #TempActivity a 
INNER JOIN #TempPerson p ON a.AID = p.ActivityID
  WHERE FirstName = 'John'
AND Surname = 'Smith'

SELECT p.FirstName
    ,p.Surname
    ,CASE
        WHEN a.ActivityName = 'Jumping' THEN 'Y'
        ELSE 'N'
    END AS 'Jumping'
    ,CASE
        WHEN a.ActivityName = 'Dancing' THEN 'Y'
        ELSE 'N'
    END AS 'Dancing'
    ,CASE
        WHEN a.ActivityName = 'Walking' THEN 'Y'
        ELSE 'N'
    END AS 'Walking'
    FROM #TempActivity a 
INNER JOIN #TempPerson p ON a.AID = p.ActivityID
WHERE FirstName = 'John'
AND Surname = 'Smith'

DROP TABLE #TempActivity;
DROP TABLE #TempPerson;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT p.FirstName
    ,p.Surname
    ,CASE WHEN SUM(CASE
        WHEN a.ActivityName = 'Jumping' THEN 1
        ELSE 0 END) > 0 THEN 'Y' 
        ELSE 'N' 
    END AS 'Jumping'
    ,CASE WHEN SUM(CASE
        WHEN a.ActivityName = 'Dancing' THEN 1
        ELSE 0 END) > 0 THEN 'Y' 
        ELSE 'N'
    END AS 'Dancing'
    ,CASE WHEN SUM(CASE
        WHEN a.ActivityName = 'Walking' THEN 1
        ELSE 0 END) > 0 THEN 'Y' 
        ELSE 'N'
    END AS 'Walking'
FROM #TempActivity a 
    INNER JOIN #TempPerson p ON a.AID = p.ActivityID
WHERE FirstName = 'John'
    AND Surname = 'Smith'
GROUP BY FirstName, SurName
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just use `max()`:

```
select firstname, surname, max(jumping) as jumping,
       max(dancing) as dancing, max(walking) as walking
from #TempActivity a join
     #TempPerson p 
     on a.AID = p.ActivityID
where FirstName = 'John' and Surname = 'Smith'
group by firstname, surname;
```

Comment: Also, since it is a yes/No situation, use 1/0. Then it will work regardless of language. 
(You won't need to worry about which one comes first in the alphabet.)